# Error: Script execution timed out after 30000ms

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner, newman

I am trying to do some load testing. I am using newman in nodejs.
In my script I have async.parallel to execute several collections in parallel. Then repeat set of parallel excution every 5 sec. In each run I have the following options:

```
collection: require('./collection.json'),
environment: require('./environment.json'),
timeoutRequest : 0, // infinite timeout
delayRequest: 1000, // ms
iterationCount: 5
```

Tha main loop looks like:

```
async function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(done => setTimeout(() => done(), ms));
}

async function orchestrator() {

  for (let j = 0; j < cycles; j++)

  {
    async.parallel(runItems,
      function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
      }
    );
    await sleep(5000);
  }
```

The last 3 lines of output are:

```
code: ‘ERR_SCRIPT_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT’
}
Process exited with code 1
```

I set cycles to 500. All goes well for 70+ cycles but then I get the error mentioned.

Have you a solution or some work around I can do?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a bug in either how Newman applies default timeout values, or how they are documented.

This is how it is supposed to work ([source](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/1626#issuecomment-406866706)):

> In a nutshell, the timeout behaviour is as follows:
>
> 1. `timeout`: This is the global timeout value, the time in milliseconds for the entire collection run to complete.
> 2. `timeoutRequest`: Similar to the above, but this value is applied individually across all requests in the collection run.
> 3. `timeoutScript`: Similar to the above, but this value is applied individually across all scripts in the collection run.
>
> For any of the 3 config values above, specifying a value of 0 will result in the timeout being set to Infinity.

My findings so far:

1. I encountered a `Script execution timeout` error when running Postman 5.2.2 CLI with default settings. Opened an issue [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/2595)
2. Based on [this comment](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/1841#issuecomment-450201871) setting timeout values to `99999` may help.